# How many players allowed on a high school baseball team?

Tags: baseball

How many players can you have on a high school baseball team? In middle school last year we were allowed to have 15 players and we did but ended the season with 9.

Comment: This almost certainly depends on state/regional rules. Try to check your state's (assuming you're in the US) high school sports association website - they typically have rulebooks for these sorts of things.

Comment: If you tell us which country and state you are in, we can probably help you find the answer.